# Angular Ui-Router miss-direction URL issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i have a really strange problem with the .otherwise function of the ui router.

On pageload the user should be redirected to the login page. Work till here (more or less). The Login Page is there but when i try to login and it should be directed to the next page, the login page redirected myself the same page again but in one difference of URL Schema. When i now try to log in everything works.

Not working URL: `/admin/#/login`

working URL: `/admin/?#/login`

When i call the correct patterned page directly it works, too.

So why the ui-router route the first otherwise to this strange schema?

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to enable `html5mode` in `ui-router`

This is how you can enable it:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
```

You need to add this in your app config.
This will help you to get rid of all the `hash-tags` in the URl.
Hope it helps.